# Leer archivo JSON que contiene acentos

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un archivo JSON que contiene palabras acentuadas, para leerlo estoy ejecutando las siguientes instrucciones:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'miArchivo.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS test
```

El problema es que las palabras acentuadas se muestran, por ejemplo, así: si fuese "Entre Ríos" obtengo "Entre RÃ­os".

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server estas manejando?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando uno lee un archivo de texto, no importa la forma en que lo haga, hay un dato fundamental que por alguna razón solemos olvidar, se trata del `encoding` o codificación del archivo. Y es que todo archivo de texto, por más sencillo que sea, tiene una codificación en particular, en tu caso, hay altas chances que `miArchivo.json` este salvado como `UTF-8`. (el carácter representado por la `Ã` en `utf-8` es la `í`).

Por lo que algo que puedes probar es leer el archivo indicando esta codificación mediante el modificador `CODEPAGE = '65001'`:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'miArchivo.json', CODEPAGE = '65001', SINGLE_CLOB) AS test
```

Comment: El archivo JSON en cuestion está codificado en UTF-8 sin BOM, probé codificarlo en UTF-8 y agregar CODEPAGE = '65001' pero obtengo los  mismos resultados.

Comment: Es raro, según la documentación a partir de SQL 2016, se puede usar esta codificación. Si tienes control sobre el archivo Json, puedes probar guardarlo en `UTF-16`, que es un formato más compatible para SQL Server, léelo sin indicar el `CODEPAGE` a ver que ocurre.

Comment: Lo acabo de codificar en ANSI y funcionó, con y sin el CODEPAGE, no estoy seguro del motivo...

Comment: Si, es la solución sencilla, ANSI  en definitiva te salva un byte por caracter (seguramente Latin1 o iso-8859), el tema con esto es si la naturaleza de los datos del archivo no requieren una codificación más extendida.

Comment: En este caso solo contiene información (id, nombre, coordenadas) de las provincias de Argentina, creo que no habría mayor problema. En que situación hacer esto no es recomendable?